# Finding a certain radius of convergence

Tags: complex-analysis

Find radius of convergence of $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{ z^{2n}}{4^n} $.

Attempt: I write

$$ \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{ z^{2n}}{4^n} = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{ z^{2n}}{2^{2n}} =_{[k=2n]} \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{ z^k}{2^k} $$

Let $a_k = 1/2^k $. Then

$$ \left| \frac{ a_k}{a_{k+1}} \right| = \frac{ 1/2^k}{1/2^{k+1}} = 2 \to 2 $$

and so $R = 2$. IS this correct? I mean, am I allowed to make this substitution $k=2n$ ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it is. You can test the radius without the substitution too, if you want to be sure:
$$\left|\frac{\frac{z^{2n+1}}{2^{2n+1}}}{\frac{z^{2n}}{2^{2n}}}\right|=\left|\frac{z^{2n+1}}{2^{2n+1}}\frac{2^{2n}}{z^{2n}}\right|$$
That is just:
$$\left|\frac{z}{2}\right|$$
And the radius is then $\left|z\right|< 2$
And the sum converges to $\frac{4}{4-z^2}$, or, expressed differently: $\frac{1}{1-\left(\frac{z}{2}\right)^2}$